# PHP upload 4 images to file and path to database MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I have been bagging my head against this problem for a few days now and can't seem to find the right answer anywhere.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

End goal: let the user upload up to 4 images. check for errors. upload image using filename into the users folder on in the file system (mkdir if doesn't already exist), store file path in the corresponding part of the SQL table.

I keep changing things to get parts of the result and have now coded myself into a big rut. 
Please let me know if you have any questions or can even suggest a better way to get to the end goal.

Thanks!!

`SQL table: post_id, user_id, created, post_title, short_descrip, Long_descrip, image1, image1_cap, image2, image2_cap, image3, image3_cap, image4, image4_cap`

---

**HTML:**

```
<form method ='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/posts/p_add'>
<h1><label for = 'content'>CREATE POST:</label><br></h1>
Post Title <input type='text' name='post_title'><br><br>
Short Description <input type='text' name='shortDescrip'><br><br>
Long Description<textarea name = 'longDescrip' id = 'longDescrip'></textarea>
<br><br>

<label for="image1">Image 1:</label>
<input type="file" name="image1" id="image1"><br>
Image Caption<input type='text' name='image1_cap'><br>

<label for="image2">Image 2:</label>
<input type="file" name="image2" id="image2"><br>
Image Caption<input type='text' name='image2_cap'><br>

<label for="image3">Image 3:</label>
<input type="file" name="image3" id="image3"><br>
Image Caption<input type='text' name='image3_cap'><br>

<label for="image4">Image 4:</label>
<input type="file" name="image4" id="image4"><br>
Image Caption<input type='text' name='image4_cap'><br>

<input type = 'Submit' value = 'POST'>
</form>
```

---

**PHP:**

```
public function p_add(){
        # associate post with the user
        $_POST['user_id'] = $this->user->user_id;

        # unix timestamp for created & modified
        $_POST['created'] = Time::now();
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];

        # create file path for images
        $imgPath = '/uploads/images/'.$this->user->user_id.'/';
        if (!file_exists($imgPath)){
            mkdir($imgPath, 0777, true);
        }
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
                for($x=1; $x<=4 ; $x++){
                    //print_r($_FILES);
                    # upload the user-chosen file and save to img file

                    $image = Upload::upload($_FILES, 'uploads/images/', 
                        array("jpg", "JPG", "jpeg", "JPEG", "gif", "GIF", "png", "PNG"), $filename);
                    print_r($image);
                    # notify of error 
                    if($image == 'Invalid file type.') {
                        echo "invalid file type";
                    }
                    else {
                        # add to DB                
                        $data = Array("image".$x => $image);
                        DB::instance(DB_NAME)->insert('posts', $data);

                        # resize the image and save again
                        /*$imgObj = new Image($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/uploads/images/'.$image);
                        $imgObj->resize(100,100,"crop");
                        $imgObj->save_image($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/uploads/images/'.$image);*/
                    }
                }
            }else{
                # if there is an error let it be known
                echo "there has been an error"; 
            }

        # insert into db
        DB::instance(DB_NAME)->insert('posts', $_POST);

        # feedback
        echo "Your post was added";
    }
```

---

Upload function from framework:

```
public static function upload($file_obj, $upload_dir, $allowed_files, $new_file_name = NULL) {      

    # Access first element in file_obj array (b/c we're dealing with single file uploads only)
    $key = key($file_obj);

    $original_file_name = $file_obj[$key]['name'];
    $temp_file          = $file_obj[$key]['tmp_name'];
    $upload_dir         = $upload_dir;

    # If new file name not given, use original file name
    if($new_file_name == NULL) $new_file_name = $original_file_name;

    $file_parts  = pathinfo($original_file_name);
    $target_file = getcwd().$upload_dir . $new_file_name . "." . $file_parts['extension'];

    # Validate the filetype
    if (in_array($file_parts['extension'], $allowed_files)) {

        # Save the file
            move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$target_file);
            return $new_file_name . "." . $file_parts['extension'];

    } else {
        return 'Invalid file type.';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in indexname:

```
 if ($_FILES["file"])...
```

you have no `<input name="file">` try to check

```
 if ($_FILES["image1"]["error"] == 0)
```

and rewrite your code in this case.

UPDATE:

Very interesting Upload function... Bad solution.

Try this:

```
$image = Upload::upload(array($_FILES['image'.$x]), 'uploads/images/',
```

Comment: Thanks BaBL86, I changed that up and feel like I'm heading down the right path, with more problems to solve :) It's putting the image name, without the file path in the table with a different post_id and row for each and the other form info on another [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3061181/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-21%20at%2011.17.18%20AM%20%282%29.png) 

this has to do with that for loop I made. I'm going to keep trucking but if you see anymore of those easy errors PLEASE let me know. My finals-fried-brain would be very thankful!!

Comment: Show me your upload class.

Comment: I think, you have a problem in your logic. You use iteration with $x and doesn't use this iterator later in Uploader. You call Uploader 4 times with one variable. If you show me your Upload class, I try to find how you need to change your code.

Comment: thanks again for looking into this, I've added the upload function

Comment: now it's giving me NULL for the image file fields. Thanks for trying to  help though!!

Comment: Interesting... OK, try to rollback your Update call to your topic state and add after this line the new one: `next($_FILES);` does it help you?